# Postgres configuration to point to an encrypted file system on centos

Tags: postgresql

I am working on centos 6.2 version. I want to configure postgres with an encrypted file system. 
I have created an encrypted partition on centos using LUKS. Now i want to initialize the db cluster with this mounted partition. but i get the below error.

```
bash-4.1$ initdb -D /mnt/cryptofs/data/
could not change directory to "/root/dimple/encryption"
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale en_US.UTF-8.
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to UTF8.
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

initdb: directory "/mnt/cryptofs/data" exists but is not empty
If you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty
the directory "/mnt/cryptofs/data" or run initdb
with an argument other than "/mnt/cryptofs/data".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify `PGDATA` to be `/mnt/cryptofs/data/`, while `initdb` complains bout `/root/dimple/encryption`, which makes me think that:

- `/mnt/cryptofs/data/` is actually a symlink;
- you don't have proper permissions for the `/root/dimple/encryption` directory;
- there're some files in the `/mnt/cryptofs/data/`. Make sure it is completely empty, no hidden files and no `lost+found` directory also.

It'd be good to see what is `/mnt/cryptofs/data/` and what are the permissions.